# How to inject authorization logic through IQueryable<TEntity> into EFCore before a sql statement is rendered?

Tags: odata, ef-core-2.2

I am currently working on getting myself a generic `OData API` using `aspnetcore` and `efcore`.

The whole generic part is working just fine. However getting the authorization to work the way i need it is now the tricky part.

What i am looking for from a authorization standpoint is:

> 1. Check if authenticated user has access to a type: very easy to
>      accomplish
> 2. property level authorization: aka strip `$select=columnA, columnB` values from the result
> 3. Identity level authorization: aka check if user has access to article with `id` 1, etc

**My goal is maximum performance.**

(1) Is essentially hardly any effort using custom authorization on the attributes validating against a cache.

(2)  Is there a hook I can abuse to transform what `OData` returns? Essentially if a user has no permission to see values for specific columns of a type i want to omit those columns from the result, even if the user selected them.

(3) Id level authorization is the really tricky one. **How can i hook myself into the `IQueryable<TEntity>` at a state before `EFCore` turns it into a `SQL` statement?** This is the place where i would have to inject my authorization logic in order to have statements executed which provide the maximum of performance, while sustaining a functional paging mechanism.

My first idea for (3) was using a result filter at `aspnetcore` level, but that might leave the user at a state where his paging control says `"show max 30 items, page 1/39"` and he might look at page 5 which has just 1 result because of his authorization and response filtering instead of just getting a dataset which matches his authorization.

The code can be pulled from https://github.com/taori/Sandbox.git

Any pointers/help regarding (2) and (3) are welcome - Perhaps someone made experience in this area and is willing to share.

In the past days I haven't really really found anyone else's authorization approaches which required going down to the `EFCore` query level.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution was fairly simple thanks to dependency injection.

i turned this:

```
[EnableQuery]
[GenericODataControllerNamingConvention]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/odata/[controller]")]
public class GenericODataController<TEntity> : ODataController
    where TEntity : class
{
    public AdventureWorksContext Context { get; }

    public GenericODataController(AdventureWorksContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> All() => Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();

    [Route("{id}")]
    public Task<TEntity> Id(int id) => Context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id);
}
```

into this:

```
public interface IAuthorization<TEntity>
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> BatchApply(IQueryable<TEntity> source);
    bool Apply(TEntity source);
}

[EnableQuery]
[GenericODataControllerNamingConvention]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/odata/[controller]")]
public class GenericODataController<TEntity> : ODataController
    where TEntity : class
{
    public AdventureWorksContext Context { get; }

    public ImmutableArray<IAuthorization<TEntity>> Authorizations { get; }

    public GenericODataController(AdventureWorksContext context, IEnumerable<IAuthorization<TEntity>> authorizations)
    {
        Context = context;
        Authorizations = authorizations.ToImmutableArray();
    }

    private TEntity ApplyAuthorization(TEntity source)
    {
        return (Authorizations.Length == 0 || Authorizations.All(d => d.Apply(source))) ? source : default;
    }

    private IQueryable<TEntity> ApplyAuthorizations(IQueryable<TEntity> source)
    {
        var latest = source;
        foreach (var authorization in Authorizations)
        {
            latest = authorization.BatchApply(latest);
        }
        return latest;
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> All() => ApplyAuthorizations(Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable());

    [Route("{id}")]
    public async Task<TEntity> Id(int id) => ApplyAuthorization(await Context.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false));
```

Since dependency injection is used here i can inject relevant authentication parameters (like the logged in user for example) and implement the specifics in the implementation for IAuthorization itself.

Comment: Very poor answer lacking fundamental details. Moreover to me it seems that using ApplyAuthorization you are materializing the query to get the data and apply some sort of filter to then return another IQueryable, but this IQueryable is based on an IEnumerable meaning al expansions or additiona OData operations which are normally applied after the controller method returns, will not work.